# Configuring multiple boot images on WDS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, boot, pxe-boot, wds

For my WDS server I installed Windows XP to Windows 10. Including all the server variations as well. Each disk comes with a boot.wim file. Is there any reason I need to load all these boot.wim files in to WDS or can I just use one Windows boot.wim file?

Comment: What Windows server version are you running?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 is what is running WDS

Comment: You should be able to use then windows 10 boot image to deploy everything from Windows Vista to 10. Of course I would recommend having the 32 and 64 bit versions but technically you should be able to get away with the 32bit version by itself. I am not sure about Windows XP. That was before the WIM format.

Comment: Don't forget to test the deployment using a Windows 10 boot image before you go and delete the platforms boot image.